# arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, android, ffmpeg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to configure ffmpeg for android on windows 10 through **bash** Ubuntu terminal. I am follow [this tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/2011/07/17/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/) But getting error.

Error is

```
C:/Users/BIP042.BIPADBBSR/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/ffmpeg-2.2.3/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64//bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.
```

what to do?

this is my build_android.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=C:/Users/BIP042.BIPADBBSR/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-         bundle/sources/ffmpeg-2.2.3
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-22/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/
function build_one
{
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
 make clean
 make
 make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```